# How to say "to ask for directions"?

Tags: vocabulario

In Spanish, how would you say "to ask for directions?"

I think it would be "Preguntar por direcciones".

---

---

#### Research I have done

In researching this, I see a lot of conflicting information.

**Google**

`Preguntar por direcciones` does appear a lot when searching on Google. It does not appear on [Google Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1500&year_end=2019&content=Preguntar%20por%20direcciones&corpus=32&smoothing=3&direct_url=), which is a good sign that it may not be common.

**Spanish Dict**

[Spanish dict](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/pedir%20indicaciones) lists it as `pedir indicaciones`. However, as an English speaker, that sounds more to me like to `to ask/to order instructions`. Indeed, searching for that phrase on Google does turn up articles about instructions rather than directions.

**Word Reference**

Word Reference has two threads on this:
[Thread 1](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ask-for-directions.2958196/)
[Thread 2](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ask-for-directions.1318716/)

The opinions shared in these threads are mixed. Some say `direcciones` and `instructions` are interchangeable. Others says they are not.

Comment: You might want to consider _pedir direcciones_ as well.

Comment: Just to be careful, **direction** and **dirección** are false cognates, _direction_ means **command**, while _dirección_ means **address**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The grammatically closest translation would be "Pedir indicaciones", but the most common way (in Spanish from Spain) is "Preguntar cómo ir/llegar".

Comment: `Preguntar cómo ir` and `Preguntar cómo llegar` would these be understood outside of Spain or are they unique to the region only.

Comment: @big_smile **preguntar cómo llegar** will work everywhere

Answer (score 3):

Well, in Spanish we would say "pedir indicaciones". It is the most common way in my opinion and perfectly correct. You wouldn't say "preguntar por direcciones" considering that you are expecting instructions on how to arrive to the address you are going to. Remember "dirección" is a false friend as it isn't the same as "direction" unless you are talking about "dirección" as a synonym of "rumbo" (What direction "dirección" are you heading? North). It is quite tricky indeed. But the translation for "dirección" would actually be "address". So unless you want an address, you ask for instructions on how to arrive to an address in Spanish.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your intended usage is, but the translation may not be as direct. (Or, atleast I want to bring in my feeling of a bit of a cultural difference there, something I experienced first hand— when temporary living in the US— around the issue of receiving directions.

Having to go to someone's place, the request in English would be

> Can you give me directions?

Whereas in my native country (Argentina), you would rather ask

> **¿cual es tu dirección?** [as for **final addresss**]

or, more informally

> **¿donde queda tu casa?** (Or **¿dónde vivís?**)

The subtle difference is that while we too could request for the guidance [directives], saying

> **¿Como hago para llegar?**  (Pasame las indicaciones [tell me how to get there])

It is less common for us to ask in such a way.

Rather than asking for instructions —to be guided to a place—, we normally request the final address where we are heading to (via **cuál es la dirección** [*which is the address?*]). That's probably why I found myself (culturally) more comfortable with a final address, —the destination's co-ordinates— rather than the steps (algorithm) necessary to reach a place.  I don't know, one could speculate, the probable reason may lay in the different characteristics of our cities? While in the United States they spread out into suburbs, with more variations in street shapes; many Spanish-based cities were laid out as square orthogonal numbered blocks, into a more predictable grid, and with less specifications needed.

Comment: Off topic, but regarding co-ordinates vs algorithm for an unknown location, I also prefer the co-ordinates.  And then let my GPS figure out how to get there.

Comment: @PeterM, exactly, we need clarity on the target first, details could follow, but —depending the way they are given— they could add noise and overwhelm the recipient's attention (turning them of no value if you get just part and not the whole recipe)

Comment: I think the question is "how **to say** «to ask for directions»" and this answers **how to ask for directions**. Did I misunderstand it?